# How to configure Spring Boot with multiple RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have 3 RabbitMQ clustings for different functionality.Now I want to consume these RabbitMQ clustings message in my spring boot project,What can I do?

Comment: it seems that it has to config each rabbitmq manually.